# Why does scene come up with blank white screen in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scene

I submit my app to the apple store and it is live now. But in some device after launch screen it come up with blank white screen. Before launch I tested in all devices both iPhones and iPads nothing happens like this. How can I figure out where the problem is and how can I solve it? Is it related with my code or something else ?

Comment: did you test it with iOS 9,  this question is too vague to really answer,  your best bet is to find out what devices it does not work on, and go from there with your code.  XCode now provides you with the exact build before you send it to the store, so make sure you install that build onto the broken device before resubmitting.

Comment: Now I tested in simulator iphone 4s 5s the white screen come up but in phone 6 and + normal.My friends play the game in iOS 9 with iPhone 6 no problem but iOS 9 with iPhone 5 is screen white problem again. In simulator 4s white screen problem come up but in iPhone 4s device the game work correctly

Comment: well there you go, you have some random bug in your code, possibly a timing issue. step through and fix it

Comment: background music playing and I can see the banner ads but the content does not rendered.

Comment: you do realize nobody can help you right?  Nobody can see your code or anything,  you are going to just have to step through it line by line and verify everything, don't know what else to tell you

Comment: I think I found the problem. I use all my UI pngs in assets catalog so many image sets. I change the launch scene to the game scene. And assets catalog pngs not rendered but texture atlas and game sprites render. When  the game have some many image sets in asset catalog rendering is take time and cannot complete the task I think. What do you think ?

Comment: Still no way for anyone to know.